# Rails3, JQuery and RJS (UJS) 

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I am trying to get ajax callbacks working on a href using remote.  I have the rails.js and 
 JQuery1.6 installed.

Here is the attempt to catch the callback:

```
$('#choo').bind('ajax:success', function(){
    alert("Success!");

});
```

Here is my div and AJAX link

```
<%= link_to "Choose", {:action => "choose", :id => 538}, :remote => true, :id => "choo" %>
```

When I click the link the ajax fires hits the server and returns the response but the callback is not working...

I have followed everything in [this](http://www.alfajango.com/blog/rails-3-remote-links-and-forms/) guide but with little by the way of success.  In other words "!ajax:success" :-).

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

EDIT++++++++++++++++++++==

I updated to 3.1 and it worked.

Cheers,

s

Comment: Did you try binding to the `ajax:beforeSend`? Not sure how Rails' UJS works, so less sure if `ajaxStart` would work the same way as with raw jQuery.

Comment: @Dave Newton.  I did what you suggested bu still no dice.  Thanks for the comment though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to "live"

```
$('#choo').live('ajax:success', function(){
  alert("Success!");
});
```

or this:

```
$('a[data-remote],input[data-remote]').live('ajax:success', function() {
  alert('success');
});
```

Comment: I've tried both of these but let me try them again and I'll get back to you.

Comment: Nope, neither of these work, which makes me thing there may be some thing wrong with rails.js....